# Is it possible to connect a Java web app to SQL Server in Virtualbox?

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc, virtualbox

I have a Mac running OS X 10.9 with Java 1.7 using Eclipse Luna. I also have MySQL and MySQL Workbench. However, my programming subject only teaches JDBC using SQL Server. I don't mind learning how to use JDBC with MySQL as the DBMS. But I was wondering if I can connect my app to a virtual machine running Windows 7 with SQL Server 2008 on Virtualbox?

TL;DR:
Java web app (Mac) <---connect---> SQL Server (Virtualbox Windows 7), possible?

Comment: Yes, sure. You will probably have to configure port forwarding on the Virtual Box to make the SQL server port visible to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of curse you can.
You will have to configure some port forwarding from your VirtualBox and maybe Windows itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll research more on the subject of port forwarding. Hopefully I can set it up pretty nicely. :)

Comment: Bridged mode will work too, it basically sets the vm on the  same IP scheme, same subnet & same gateway.